# Передача переменных из одного метода в другой

Tags: c#

```
class Test
{
    public int x = 2;
    public int y = 3;
    public int z = 4;

    public void XYZ()
    {
        int a = x + y + z;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }

    public void ABC()
    {
        int b = a + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test q = new Test();

        q.XYZ();
        q.ABC();
    }
}
```

Добрый день, задался вопросом, как можно передавать значения переменных из одного метода в другой, пробовал разными способами, но ничего не выходит, так же пробовал через параметр и в строке "q.ABC()" появлялась ошибка (Ошибка  CS7036  Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "a" из "Test.ABC(int)".). Понимаю, что программа не видит, что я передаю, что туда нужно вписать, чтобы всё заработало? И какие ещё способы можно использовать? (Функции и тд)

Comment: Ну у вас же есть уже поля класса, можно ещё `a` завести. Пока что это локальная переменная

Comment: А как это реализовать? @MBo

Comment: Вы  `public int z = 4;` во сне, что ли писали? Точно так же. Вероятно, вместо public понадобится private, если не хотите, чтобы снаружи класса это поле было видимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классика, возвращаемые значения и аргументы методов.

```
class Test
{
    public int x = 2;
    public int y = 3;
    public int z = 4;

    public int XYZ()
    {
        int a = x + y + z;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        return a;
    }

    public void ABC(int a)
    {
        int b = a + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test q = new Test();

        int a = q.XYZ();
        q.ABC(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужен был способ с методами Void, уже разобрался

Comment: @raiikkenn74 ок, в следующий раз пишите подробнее условия задачи